# Track selected remote directories in git-svn

Tags: git-svn

I have a large SVN repository with a pretty messy history. I want to use git locally to track a few selected directories from this repository. Also, I need the local folder structure be different from that of the SVN, so this is not only about the tracking being sparse. My local layout should look like this:

```
git directories      remote svn path
---------------      ---------------
/                      (not tracked)
+-/Core              https://svn/main/Core/dev
+-/Apps                (not tracked)
  +-/Foo             https://svn/main/Apps/Foo/dev
  +-/Bar             https://svn/main/Apps/Bar/dev
```

There is only a handful of directories under `Apps` that I want to track. Also, later in life of the local git repository, I must be able to start tracking another app(s) from the same remote SVN repository.

Is this doable more or less cleanly? I am thinking about tracking each directory as a separate svn remote, but I am not sure if there is not a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by tracking as a separate svn remote you mean having independent git repositories pointing to the desired svn folder, then this is perfectly doable. The only complication you might have is syncing to and from svn, especially when the number of the linked projects will grow. You might want then to create a simple script that would execute command like `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit` against all the subprojects to minimize manual labour.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, and this is obvious enough a solution to track every svn subtree directory in a separate git repo. I hoped there would be a more elegant solution, but I could not find one. Looks like what I am looking for is just not possible.